# Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s) with question marks

Tags: c, valgrind

Here is my code:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    int* temp = malloc(sizeof(int));
    *temp = 10; 
    free(temp);
    return 0;
}
```

but when I try to use valgrind on it, I get a ton of errors like

```
Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)
    at 0x41C540: ??? (in /home/path)
    by 0x4711EA: ??? (in /home/path)
    by 0x448DE4: ??? (in /home/path)
    by 0x44A995: ??? (in /home/path)
    by 0x40249B: ??? (in /home/path)
    by 0x401B6D: ??? (in /home/path)
    by 0x1FFF000657: ???
```

and I can't understand why I get them.

Adding `--track-origins=yes` doesn't change the errors.

I also tried using `calloc` instead of `malloc`, but the errors remain.

Can someone help me?

Comment: Can you put the exact Valgrind command that you run? I can't replicate the error with `valgrind --track-origins=yes ./YourProgram`. Thanks

Comment: Please provide the details of the compiler flags if any used.

Comment: @Sarwagya I run the same command that you posted, `valgrind --track-origins=yes ./a.out`

Comment: @SourabhChoure none used, just `gcc program.c`

Comment: You should check whether the call to `malloc` at `int* temp = malloc(sizeof(int));` was successful in the first place. Use `int* temp = malloc(sizeof(int)); if(!temp) { fputs("Error at allocation!", stderr); }`.

Comment: `valgrind --tool=memcheck --track-origins=yes ./a.out` Did you tried this too?

Comment: @RobertSsupportsMonicaCellio true. Memory gets successfully allocated

Comment: @SourabhChoure tried now, nothing changed

Comment: What OS / CPU architecture / etc, and how was valgrind installed?  This seems like either a bug in valgrind, an OS or configuration it doesn't support well, or a mis-installation.

Comment: @NateEldredge I'm using Ubuntu LTS 18.04 on an Intel i5 6500, valgrind was installed from Ubuntu repo's

Answer (score 1):

To give more precise stack traces containing line numbers and file name, valgrind uses the debug info.

You should compile with the -g option.

Note however that I do not see how the small code you have shown could create errors.  So, clearly, these errors are arriving from system libraries.  Such errors should then not be shown.  So, likely your valgrind installation is strange and/or the setup of your system libraries is not typical.

Comment: It seems to me that the code ought not create *any* errors.

Comment: @NateEldredge I clarified the answer according to your comment.